# Math in Java problem with GTGE

Tags: java, math, trigonometry, game-engine

I have a GTGE game and I am having some problems with the math. I don't understand why it isn't moving the way I want it to. When you click somewhere the sprite moves right there. When you right-click it calculates the angle and moves there, but it doesn't stop. I capture the position of the mouse and every time it updates the screen i check to see if the sprite has reached the position, but when it does it doesn't stop. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import com.golden.gamedev.Game;
import com.golden.gamedev.GameLoader;
import com.golden.gamedev.object.Background;
import com.golden.gamedev.object.Sprite;
import com.golden.gamedev.object.background.ImageBackground;


public class SpriteTest extends Game {
    //Default Background
    Background  background;
    //Toolkit!
    Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    //Main Sprite
    Sprite pacman;
    Dimension stop;

    @Override
    public void initResources() {

        //Load the background
        background = new ImageBackground(getImage("nature-wallpapers.jpg"));
        //Load the Sprite
        pacman = new Sprite(getImage("pacman.png"));
        pacman.setActive(false);
        pacman.setBackground(background);


        playMusic("intro.mid");
        showCursor();



    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D g) {

        //Render background
        background.render(g);
        //Render sprites

        pacman.render(g);




    }

    @Override
    public void update(long elapsedTime) {  
        //Update the background
        background.update(elapsedTime);
        //Update sprites

        if(click()) {


            pacman.setActive(true);
            pacman.setLocation(getMouseX(), getMouseY());


        }



        if(rightClick()) {
            int spriteLocX = (int) pacman.getX();
            int spriteLocY = (int) pacman.getY();
            int mouseX = getMouseX();
            int mouseY = getMouseY();
            pacman.setMovement(1, -(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(mouseY - spriteLocY, mouseX - spriteLocX ))));
            stop = new Dimension(mouseX, mouseY);

        }

            if(stop != null) {
                if(pacman.getX() == stop.getWidth()) {
                    if(pacman.getY() == stop.getHeight()){
                        pacman.setMovement(0, 0);
                    }

                }
            }
            pacman.update(elapsedTime);






    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameLoader game = new GameLoader();
        game.setup(new SpriteTest(), new Dimension(800,600), true);
        game.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that he's moving too far so he's never exactly on the 'stop' position. If he moves let's say 10 units each time-step, you can assume he'll only ever be on the stop position at the end of any given time-step once in 10 attempts.

I would calculate the distance you have to go when you click. Then you can multiply the number of time-steps that have occured since you were told to move times the distance you move each tick. When this multiplcation is greater than the pythagorean distance between your original point and the destination, you can set your movement to 0 and your position to the destination. (Do this before you render, obviously)